# Subdomain or subdirectors (SEO point of view)?

Tags: seo, subdomain, subdirectory

What is better out of the SEO view?

- **Subdomain**: separate areas by subdomain, by splitting into several smaller sites
- **Subdirectory**: Single big site, separating areas by directory

Thanks.

Christopher

**Edit:** Yes, I know, I could redirect from subdomain to subdirectory or vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here :

- http://www.searchenginejournal.com/subdomains-or-subfolders-which-are-better-for-seo/6849/
- http://www.seochat.com/c/a/Search-Engine-Optimization-Help/Proper-Domain-Subdomain-and-Folder-URL-Structure-Management-in-SEO/

I don't have a straight answer. It depends on many things (content, traffic, services, cross domain actions, ...)

You may have more accurate answers on https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks. The links were perfect! I'll be using subdirectories instead of subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

Search engines and crawlers treat sub-domains uniquely and separately from the main domain. That's the reason why even though you get hosted by blogspot or wordpress you not going to find your blog anytime soon unless you do some work!

Sub Folder These are web pages which are physically and structurally found on the root domain/website (a sub domain can have a sub folder, but a sub folder can't have a sub.domain) but in lower level, so to speak.

Sub folders have a lot to do with hierarchy and file structure. They are treated as part of the main domain, however, the search engines see them as inner pages so it's harder (but not impossible) to get good ranking for sub folders pages.